# How to stretch nav bar and should I create a side div or background image?

Tags: html, css

I have two problems I can't seem to figure out.

For whatever reason I cannot seem to stretch out the nav bar to fill the height/length of the `div` next to it (`div#textarea`) while keeping the text of the menu itself positioned in the center of that `div`.

Another problem is I want to create a side bar on the right of the page. Now the thing is, should I create a `div` for that too, or should I create a full background image? (Everything in the background 'image' is white besides the side bar, which will be in a different colour.)

Here is an image of what I have so far with red lines showing where I want them:

[image: nav bar and side bar problem]

*(The purple `div` at the bottom was originally going to be the side bar, I put some text in it so you can see it's there)*

Basically, summarised, these are my questions:

1. **How do I stretch out the nav bar in length/height?**
2. **Should I create a side `div` or background image or perhaps something else?** (Note: The image of the logo in the top right has partially the )

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
#page {
  margin: 0 auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#nav,
#textarea,
#contactallpages {
  display: inline-block;
}
#containerpage {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#centercontainer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5%;
}
#nav {
  background: #aaaaaa;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 1%;
  border-radius: 25% 0% 0% 0%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#textarea {
  background: #cccccc;
  height: 70%;
  width: 60%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding: 3%;
  border-radius: 0% 10% 0% 0%;
  text-align: left;
}
#contactallpages {
  background: #bbbbbb;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 1%;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-radius: 0% 5% 25% 0%;
}
#purplebanner {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerpage">
  <div id="centercontainer">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">more</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">links</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">in menut</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--

        -->
    <div id="textarea">
      <header>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </header>
      <p>
        text text text
      </p>
      <p>
        text text text
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--

        -->
    <div id="contactallpages">
      Contact info
      <br>Name person
      <br>
      <br>Address
      <br>more lines
      <br>
      <br>
      <u>Telephone:</u>
      <br>numbers
      <br>
      <u>E-mail:</u>
      <br>address thingey
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="purplebanner">
    text
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 1, I'd place an `overflow: hidden;` in your entire page container,  then break up the second container you have (`#centercontainer`).  Have nav in its own container (something like `#container_left`) with a `float: left;`. Then put all your other content into a second container (something like `#container_right`) and `float: left;` also.

A helpful tip is to do `border: 1px solid red;` on all your containers to get a visual of where your `div`s are sitting.